# Issue import vendor file in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to import a non cake php file into a view. I copied the file into the Vendors folder and then added the following line to my code:

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor', 'sitecommon');
?>
```

But this gives me the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class IncFunc in /var/www/html/PHP/site/includes/sitecommon.php on line 6
```

But if I remove the import statement I get the message:

```
Class 'IncFunc' not found in <b>/var/www/html/cakepftest/app/views/alerts/view.ctp
```

This is for cake version 1.3.7.

```
<?php


//various include functions for javascript libraries,etc.
class IncFunc
{

    static public $PHP_ROOT_PATH="/PHP";
    static public $CAKE_ROOT_PATH="/cakepftest";
    static public $JSP_ROOT_PATH="http://localhost:8080/JSPDataSource";


    static function icon()
    {
        echo "<link href=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/site/images/favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\" rel=\"icon\" /><link href=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/site/images/favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\" rel=\"shortcut icon\" />";

    }

    static function linkStyleCSS()
    {

        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/site/includes/style.css\" type=\"text/css\" />"; 
    }

    static function logo()
    {
        echo "<a id=\"jq-siteLogo\" href=\"http://www.pikefin.com\" title=\"PikeFin Home\"><img src=\"/PHP/site/images/33pctsizecrop.jpg\"/></a>";
    }

    static function primaryNav($Page)
    {


        echo "<div id=\"jq-primaryNavigation\">\n";
        echo "<ul>\n";
        echo "<li class=\"jq-home ".($Page=="home"?"jq-current":"")."\"><a href=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/site/main/index.php\" title=\"Pikefin Home\">Home</a></li>\n";
        echo "<li class=\"jq-alerts ".($Page=="alerts"?"jq-current":"")."\"><a href=\"".self::$CAKE_ROOT_PATH."/users/chart\" title=\"Pikefin Alert Manager\">Alert Manager</a></li>\n";
        echo "<li class=\"jq-charts ".($Page=="charts"?"jq-current":"")."\"><a href=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/charts/allassets/topchart.php\" title=\"Pikefin Charts\">Charts</a></li>";
        //echo "<li class=\"jq-blog ".($Page=="blog"?"jq-current":"")."\"><a href=\"/PHP/site/main/blog.php\" title=\"Pikefin Blog\">Blog</a></li>";
        //echo "<li class=\"jq-about ".($Page=="about"?"jq-current":"")."\"><a href=\"/PHP/site/main/about.php\" title=\"About Pikefin\">About</a></li>";
        echo "</ul>\n";
        echo "</div><!-- /#primaryNavigation -->\n";




    }

    static function incJquery()
    {

        echo "<script src=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/site/includes/jquery-1.5.1.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
    }

    static function header1($context)
    {
        //require_once '../../common/functions.php';
        echo "<div id=\"jq-header\" >";
        self::logo();
        self::primaryNav($context);
        //self::pageCounter();
        echo "</div> <!-- header -->";
    }


    static function pageCounter()
    {


        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if (strpos($uri,'?')!=false)
            $uri = substr($uri,0,strpos($uri,'?'));

        db_utility::db_connect();

        $query1 = "select hits from page_counters where uri='".$uri."'";

        $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die("Failed Query of " . $query1);

        $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

        if ($row1==null)
        {
            $query2 = "insert into page_counters (uri,hits) values ('".$uri."',1)";
        }
        else 
        {
            $query2 = "update page_counters set hits=".($row1['hits']+1)." where uri='".$uri."'";
        }

        mysql_query($query2) or die("Failed Query of " . $query2);




    }

    static function chartSecondaryNav()
    {

        echo "<div id=\"jq-secondaryNavigation\">\n";
        echo "<ul>\n";
        echo "<li class=\"jq-fedreserve jq-first\"><a href=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/charts/fed/balsheet.php\">Federal Reserve Main</a></li>\n";
        echo "<li class=\"jq-allassets\"><a href=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/charts/allassets/tablesample3A.php\">All Assets</a></li>\n";
        echo "<li class=\"jq-forex\"><a href=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/charts/forex/forex.php\">Foreign Exchange</a></li>\n";
        echo "<li class=\"jq-commodities\"><a href=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/charts/commods/commodities.php\">Commodities</a></li>\n";
        echo "<li class=\"jq-equities jq-last\"><a href=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/charts/usequities/usequities.php\">U.S Equities</a></li>\n";
        echo "</ul>\n";
        echo "</div><!-- /#secondaryNavigation -->\n";

    }

    static function yuiDropDownJavaScript()
    {

        echo "  <!-- Combo-handled YUI CSS files: -->";
        //echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.8.2r1/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css\">";
        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.8.2r1/build/menu/assets/skins/sam/menu.css\">";
        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.8.2r1/build/button/assets/skins/sam/button.css\">";
        echo "<!-- Combo-handled YUI JS files: -->";
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.8.2r1/build/yuiloader-dom-event/yuiloader-dom-event.js&2.8.2r1/build/container/container_core-min.js&2.8.2r1/build/menu/menu-min.js&2.8.2r1/build/element/element-min.js&2.8.2r1/build/button/button-min.js\"></script>";

        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."/site/includes/yuiDropDown.js\"></script>";

        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";

        echo "var rootpath='".self::$PHP_ROOT_PATH."';";
        //echo "var rootpath='/PHP';";
        //echo "var rootpath='/phptest';";

        echo "YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady(\"productsandservices\", yuiCallBack);";
        echo "</script>";


    }

    static function yuiDropDownMenu()
    {

        echo "<div class=\"yui-skin-sam\" id=\"yahoo-com\" style=\"padding: 0 160px;\">";
        echo "  <div id=\"doc\" class=\"yui-t1\" width=\"30em\">";
        echo "      <div id=\"productsandservices\" class=\"yuimenubar yuimenubarnav\">";
        echo "          <div class=\"bd\">";
        echo "              <ul class=\"first-of-type\">";
        echo "              <li class=\"yuimenubaritem first-of-type\">";
        echo "                  <a class=\"yuimenubaritemlabel\" >Equities</a>";
        echo "              </li>";
        echo "              <li class=\"yuimenubaritem\">";
        echo "                  <a class=\"yuimenubaritemlabel\" >Commodities</a>";
        echo "              </li>";
        echo "              <li class=\"yuimenubaritem\">";
        echo "                  <a class=\"yuimenubaritemlabel\" >Foreign Exchange</a>";
        echo "              </li>";
        echo "              <li class=\"yuimenubaritem\">";
        echo "                  <a class=\"yuimenubaritemlabel\" >Miscellaneous</a>";
        echo "              </li>";
        echo "              </ul>";
        echo "          </div>";
        echo "      </div>";
        echo "  </div>";
        echo "</div>";





    }

    static function blogFeedJavaScript()
    {
        echo "<script src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAxIClsZ3ToqpAEYJ0xpbYDBQvMn8QNL-nLRnNjyJkuSEqYss18BSxvSrpXIIMYm_A6P2cdVBEmC64UA\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\n";
        echo "<script language=\"Javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">    \n";
        echo "/*\n";
        echo " *  How to use the Feed Control to grab, parse and display feeds.\n";
        echo "*/\n";

        echo "google.load(\"feeds\", \"1\");\n";

        echo "function OnLoad() {\n";
        echo "/* Create a feed control */\n";
        echo "var feedControl = new google.feeds.FeedControl();\n";

        echo "/* Add two feeds. */\n";
        echo "feedControl.addFeed(\"http://pikefin.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default\", \"Pikefin Blog\");\n";

        echo "/* Draw it.*/\n";
        echo "feedControl.draw(document.getElementById(\"blogcontrol\"))\n";
        echo "}\n";

        echo "google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);\n";
        echo "</script>\n";



    }

}



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you're declaring the class `IncFunc` twice, like:

```
class IncFunc {
   ...
}

// somewhere else
class IncFunc {
   ...
}
```

Remove one of the declarations.

Comment: It's only in there once. The same file works fine outside of cake. I'll attach the code above.

Comment: Well, you were right. Another developer was including it through default.ctp.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really solve the problem of why it's happening, but you could:

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('IncFunc')) {
    App::import('Vendor', 'sitecommon');
}

?>
```